# Typescript type is missing the following properties while props are defined as optional

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I defined the properties in my `index.tsx` like this:

```
interface Props {
  uuid: string
  cdn?: string
  filename?: any
  classname?: any
  [key: string]: any
}

export const UCImage = ({
  uuid,
  cdn = 'https://ucarecdn.com/',
  filename,
  classname,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  // ...
}
```

And I add the component like this in my `App.tsx`:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <UCImage
      uuid='83c3bad4-b4bc-4cea-8702-88ee61b0b015'
      preview={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
      setFill={{ color: 'ff0000' }}
    />
  )
}
```

Somehow I still get the error:

> Type '{ uuid: string; preview: { width: number; height: number; };
> setFill: { color: string; }; }' is missing the following properties
> from type 'Props': filename, classname

while the `filename` and `classname` are both optional parameters. Anyone with more experience in Typescript that can tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: [Works on the TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3XpAW).

Comment: The code works but the error just shows up when I open the page. Guess I should ignore the error then . @T.J.Crowder

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that TypeScript doesn't emit that error for the code in the question. The error you've quoted is clearly a TypeScript error, but the code you're getting it from must not be the code in the question.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  If we can't see the problem then we can't easily suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a another way of defining `type` for a functional component, instead of assigning the `Props` interface to the component parameters you can use the `React.FC` Class as a type.

```
export const UCImage: React.FC<Props> = ({uuid, cdn, filename, classname,
...props}) => {
    //...
}
```

maybe this will solve your problem.